# knockout.js won't update my foreach binding although the change is registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to animate objects inside an `observableArray` using jQuery's `animate` method. To do this I am using a mediator copy of the array that I animate and then reapply its value to the `observableArray` like:

```
function VM(){
    var self = this;
    this.array =  ko.observableArray([{val:2},{val:4}]);
    this.array.subscribe(function(changeset){
        console.log('updating values', JSON.stringify(self.array())); //this fires just fine
    });
};

var model = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(model);
var mediator = ko.toJS(model.array);


var target = [{val:200},{val:400}];

$.each(mediator, function(i, el){
    $(el).animate(target[i], {
        duration : 500,
        progress : function(){
            model.array(mediator);
        }
    });
});
```

The values update just fine (the subscribed function fires and delivers the right results), yet when I try to bind this against this view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: array">
    <p data-bind="text:val"></p>
</div>
```

it never updates. See a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKALt/2/

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why is your solution is not working, and I also don't know why this: http://jsfiddle.net/BHhPg/ fixes it... so I will have a  deeper look into it.

Comment: @nemesv I think the problem ist with swapping the whole array at once, I've seen people pushing and poppin observableArrays one by one to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out: the array assignment `model.array(mediator);` triggers the array change event. But the `foreach` binding is optimized so it only renders out the added/removed/changes elements but you are always reasigning your `array` prop with the **same instances** where the properties are not observables so KO won't render out the DOM. If you clone the `mediator` object with `JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(mediator))` then your original code also works: http://jsfiddle.net/gXgEm/

Comment: @nemesv Great, that's good way to tackle my problem I guess. Don't mind to add that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get something working, tell me if it helps, see this fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/JKALt/3/

The main change is

```
this.array =  ko.observableArray([ko.observable({val:2}),ko.observable({val:4})]);
```

I think the problem is the following : the fact you create an observable array does not imply that the objects in the array are observable. You have to make the items in the array observable.

> **Key point**: An observableArray tracks which objects **are in** the array, not **the state** of those objects

from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Also note that you have to update the values of the observables. I think a better way of updating can be worked out though.

```
progress : function(){
  model.array()[0](mediator[0]);
  model.array()[1](mediator[1]);
}
```